# Ошибка при установке GULP SASS

Tags: node.js, gulp, sass

Открываю cmd, пишу

> npm i --save-dev gulp gulp-sass

в ответ же получаю:

```
PS F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest> npm i --save-dev gulp gulp-sass
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> node-sass@4.14.1 install F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-88_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-88_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: F:\Programming\NodeJS\node.exe F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'F:\\Programming\\NodeJS\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'F:\\Projects\\Programming\\Web\\gulptest\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.1.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python F:\Programming\Python360\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: F:\Programming\Python360\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:309:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:327:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1055:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "F:\\Programming\\NodeJS\\node.exe" "F:\\Projects\\Programming\\Web\\gulptest\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd F:\Projects\Programming\Web\gulptest\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v15.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN myproject@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-06T15_19_50_188Z-debug.log
```

Весь гугл перекопал, у многих проблема решалась переустановкой node js или его обновлением, к сожалению я в число этих счастливчиков у которых так просто это решилось не вошёл(. Сижу сейчас репу чешу, как быть, что делать, если не трудно, подскажите пожалуйста как решить это.

Comment: вам сложное или простое решение?

Comment: любое, лишь бы решение

Comment: суть проблемы: у вас стоит node v15.x, вы ставите gulp-sass, который тянет node-sass версии "^4.8.3". у node-sass подходящей версии (4.14.1) нет биндинга под винду, под 15тую ноду. такого биндинга нет, так что он пробует собраться локально, но это невозможно так как у вас не установлен python2.

Comment: простейший способ решения - даунгрейт node до 14 версии. посложнее: [установить все пререквизиты](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows), которые нужны gyp для работы и попробовать собрать node-sass под ваше окружение. ещё можно попробовать установить node-sass последней, 5 версии, и попробовать после этого установить gulp-sass

Comment: спасибо, это помогло